# Remove timestamp when converting datestring to date using pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a date given as String. After working to_datetime on it, it still has the time in it?

```
 pickedDate = '2016-09-23'
 pickedDate = pandas.to_datetime(pickedDate,format='%Y-%m-%d')
 print(pickedDate)
```

> Console Log: 2016-09-23 00:00:00

What i want is: i have Dataframe with the Date as index. I want to search for all entries which is same with `pickedDate`.

i tried:

```
print(dataframe.loc[pickedDate])
```

but that gives me:

> KeyError: 'the label [2016-09-23 00:00:00] is not in the [index]'

Dataframe looks like (head):

```
DATE         INT            VALL                      
2005-11-10  00:00:00.000      0
2005-11-10  00:30:00.000      0
2005-11-10  01:00:00.000      0
2005-11-10  01:30:00.000      1
2005-11-10  02:00:00.000      1
```

Comment: Try `df.loc['2016-09-23']`?

Comment: that Works. But i need the pickedDate variable (somewhere else as datetime). i thought the format parameter as i did would remove the time? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the format of your index (`YYYY-MM-DD`), this would work:

```
df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2005-11-10', '2005-11-10', '2005-11-10', '2005-11-10',
               '2005-11-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='DATE', freq=None)

df.loc['2005-11-10']

                     INT  VALL
DATE                          
2005-11-10  00:00:00.000     0
2005-11-10  00:30:00.000     0
2005-11-10  01:00:00.000     0
2005-11-10  01:30:00.000     1
2005-11-10  02:00:00.000     1
```

Pandas is smart enough to work with strings when accessing the datetime index. So, in your case, you'd do:

```
pickedDate = '2016-09-23'
df.loc[pickedDate]
```

This would *also* work if your index is a list of strings:

```
df.index
Index(['2005-11-10', '2005-11-10', '2005-11-10', '2005-11-10', '2005-11-10'], dtype='object', name='DATE')

Idf.loc['2005-11-10']
                     INT  VALL
DATE                          
2005-11-10  00:00:00.000     0
2005-11-10  00:30:00.000     0
2005-11-10  01:00:00.000     0
2005-11-10  01:30:00.000     1
2005-11-10  02:00:00.000     1
```

However, if you are using a index with dates, I would suggest converting them to datetime as [John Zwinck mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259142/4909087). Once you convert, your current method will *also* work.

Comment: Your Alternatively Part does not work with .date(), it gives me 'KeyError: 'the label [2016-09-23] is not in the [index]'

Comment: @M.Meooa That means your index is actually a list of strings.

Comment: Ahh..got it.  Thanks

Comment: So you said pandas can handle dates as string and its not necessary convert strings to datetime to compare them, right? @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: @M.Meooa If you want to perform any date related operations (aggregation and computation based on dates/days of week/etc), it is better to convert. Otherwise, it matters not.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your DataFrame index contains strings.  So you can search it with strings:

```
dataframe.loc[str(pickedDate.date())]
```

Or you can change the index dtype:

```
dataframe.index = pd.to_datetime(dataframe.index)
```

Comment: Not necessarily. This works with a datetime index too.